# Odd behavior of UPPER in select

Tags: mysql, uppercase

I am trying to do some string manipulated within a MySQL select and I seem to have some strange behavior from the UPPER function.

I am trying to return the first letter of a word (delimited with spaces) and convert it to upper case. However if I use UPPER on the single returned letter I get a blank, while if I use UPPER on the whole word before getting the first letter from it I do get the first letter.

Stripping the SQL down to the minimum I have come up with this test SQL:-

```
SELECT 
    'verbatim h', 
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(' ','verbatim h',' '), ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1, 1),
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(' ','verbatim h',' '), ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1, 1)),
    SUBSTRING(UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(' ','verbatim h',' '), ' ', 2), ' ', -1)), 1, 1)
```

This is taking the string 'verbatim h', concatenating spaces at either end then getting the string between the 1st and 2nd space (so it will get *verbatim*).

The first column is the full string, the 2nd column is the first letter of the first word, the 3rd column is the first letter converted to upper case of the first word while the 4th column is the first letter of the first word converted to upper case.

I think columns 3 and 4 should have the same values (the only difference being that one converts the 1st word to upper case before grabbing the first letter, while the other grabs the 1st letter then converts it to upper case), but instead one contains the letter **V** as I would expect while the other contains blank.

If I modify the above to get the HEX values of the resulting characters, the blank one is a 1 character string with hex value 00, while the V is a hex value of 56.

Any suggestions? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: For those finding this in the future, it seems to have been fixed for MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

The string becomes a binary string. And for these you can't use `LOWER` and `UPPER`, as stated in the [mysql reference docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper)

**So how to solve?**

Use the `convert` funcion like this:

```
SELECT 
    'verbatim h', 
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(' ','verbatim h',' '), ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1, 1) AS c1,
    UPPER(CONVERT((SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(' ','verbatim h',' '), ' ', 2), ' ', -1), 1, 1)) USING latin1)) AS c1_upper;
```

here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/68b32/1/0)

Comment: Interesting. I think you are right, but not sure why MySQL has decided to treat the result of a SUBSTRING against a string as being binary. Especially as if you use the example SQL as a subselect and then do an UPPER on the 2nd column it gives the correct result.

Comment: i is a bit strange, true. I did not follow deeper into the logic of mysql string functions and when they return with binary strings. I guess it is some for of "optimization" that kicks in for single character strings.

Comment: Mmm, not so sure having done a touch more investigation. Changing the SUBSTRINGs to get the 1st 2 characters, using UPPER on the 1st chracters returns "V " (in hex 5600) - similarly if you change it to the first 3 chars it brings the first 2 back in upper case with a low value in place of the 3rd. Looks like it is corrupting the last character of the string.